# Create list of factorials using list comprehension

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I'm trying to build a list of the first ten factorials

```
[1,1,2,6,24,120,720,5040,40320,362880]
```

using only list comprehension. Is that possible?

I don't know generators or `lambda`.

Here's my attempt, but I absolutely know why it's wrong:

```
lst = [1] + [i for i in range(1,10)]
lst[1:10] = [lst[i-1] * i for i in range(1,10)]
print(lst)
```

Comment: write a function that calculates the factorial (`def fact(n):...return res`) for a number `n` and then use a list comprehension like: `[fact(x) for x in range(10)]`

Comment: @Ev.Kounis Maybe the OP is asking us to write him a list comprehension that does not use *any* function ;)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just for fun:

One-liner mega-hack using list comprehension and an auxililary accumulator (the resulting list itself) to reuse previously computed value

```
s=[];  s=[s[-1] for x in range(1,10) if not s.append(x*s[-1] if s else 1)]
```

result:

```
[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]
```

note: The `math.factorial` answer is the way when elements are random. Here it's faster because we can reuse previous results.

There's also another drawback: the need to store all elements in a `list` because python does not allow `if` and assignment like C does. So we have to append to a list and negate the `None` it returns so `if` test is `True`

As I said: fun, but still a hack.

Comment: this is what i had in mind too ☺. 3! is just 2! * 3 and 2! is the last element on the list so far when 3! is about to be computed.

Comment: This doesn't really require both the `aux` and `s` variables—just write the second part this way: `aux = [aux[-1] for x in range(1,10) if no...`

Comment: or use just `s` :)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`math.factorial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.factorial):

```
import math

[math.factorial(n) for n in range(10)]
```

**Output:**

```
>>> import math
>>> 
>>> [math.factorial(n) for n in range(10)]
[1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880]
```

Comment: Yes, Python comes with batteries included :)

Comment: Although this is very concise, it's likely much, much slower for calculating large values of `n` since each call to `math.factorial(n)` **recomputes** all the intermediate values for 0! to (n-1)! every time it's called.

Answer (score 2):

Your attempt does not work because the list comprehension works element-wise, you cannot refer to `lst[i-1]` like that. There is a `factorial` function in `math` module, however, since you mentioned generators, you can use one like this

```
def mygenerator():
    total = 1
    current = 1
    while True:
        total *= current
        yield total
        current += 1

factorial = mygenerator()
output = [next(factorial) for i in range(10)]
```

Comment: Is this time friendly?

Comment: Yes, in contrast to the recursive solution. It does not recompute values. It gives the factorials up to 500! in less than a second. With a recursive solution, you can't get to 20!

Comment: @AkinjideBankole This solution computes `n!` by using `(n-1)!` which is already computed and does not do it all over again. So, yes. It should be even faster that the built-in `math.factorial()` for big n values

Answer (score 1):

We could also use our own function but hey, the meaning of the comprehension lists is lost a bit but it is still functional

```
def factorialIte(n):
  factorial = 1
  for i in range(1,n+1):
    factorial = factorial*i
return factorial
# 10 is n_max
[factorialIte(n) for n in range(1,11)]
>>[1, 2, 6, 24, 120, 720, 5040, 40320, 362880, 3628800]
```