# Calculating factorial with for loop with iteration

Tags: python

```
def factorial(num):
    fac=1
    if num!=0:
        fac= ((fac*i) for i in range(1,number+1)) 
    return fac
print ("Enter the number:")
number =int(input())
print (str(factorial(number)))
```

'''
comprehension is not allowed in line 4. Why so? is that a limitation?
'''

Comment: it's not a limitation but error with your code. Your comprehension should be using `num` instead of `number`. PS: There are few more errors in your code. But as far as your question is concerned, no, there is no limitation. You can use it, *whether it should be used there is a different question*

Comment: It's not a comprehension it's a [generator expression.](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) Who told you it was a comprehension?

Comment: @Quadri-I learnt its a generator and I am new to the lang. So still coping. But the parameter<num>and variable<number>should not matter as long as they are of same data type. Let me know if I'm wrong. ;)

Comment: @PeterWood-Thx for the info. Looking into generator expression.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this if your goal is to calculate a factorial

```
for i in range(2,num+1):
    fac = fac * i
```

If your goal is to generate a list up to N factorial using list comprehension then check out this post : [Create list of factorials using list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41062600/create-list-of-factorials-using-list-comprehension)

Comment: @Mitchel0022-Thanks 4 d info.  took a look at the post. Seems to be diff than what I am trying.